# Does euca2ools provide any reference script to test whether it works well with my OpenStack cluster?

Tags: openstack, eucalyptus

My OpenStack cluster has sometimes issues that impact some euca2ools' functions. For example one issue my OpenStack cluster recently had was making euca2ools' `euca-describe-instances` lags forever (no listing even after waiting a few minutes). Does euca2ools provide any reference script to test whether it works well with my OpenStack cluster?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: Since this question received no answer, I posted it on Quora: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Does-euca2ools-provide-any-reference-script-to-test-whether-it-works-well-with-my-OpenStack-cluster